# I uploaded my website to Github and it isn't reading any of the other files associated with the website

Tags: github-pages

The CSS stylesheet isn't loading, nor are any of the pictures loading.

[image: Current appearence of the site]

[The site](https://shakey0.github.io/My-Site/), [Github folder](https://github.com/shakey0/My-Site)

Answer (score 0):

It is because the mentioned URL is mismatching with the original one.
The name of the folder which contains the images is `Image` and not `image`, the difference is the letter `I`, it should be in capital.
As: You have used `<img class="mountain" src="`[images/mountain.png](https://shakey0.github.io/My-Site/images/mountain.png)`" alt="mountain-img">`, which gives an `Error 404`. Use `<img class="mountain" src="`[Images/mountain.png](https://shakey0.github.io/My-Site/Images/mountain.png)`" alt="mountain-img">` instead and it will work well.